# Is "Cartan's magic formula" due to Élie or Henri?

Tags: ho.history-overview, dg.differential-geometry

The formula $\mathcal{L}_X\omega = i_Xd\omega + d(i_X \omega)$ is sometimes attributed to Henri Cartan (e.g. Peter Petersen; Riemannian Geometry 2nd ed.; p.380) and sometimes to his father Élie (e.g. Berline, Getzler, Vergne; Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators, p.17), and often just to "Cartan" (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative ).
Who is right? Reference?

Comment: http://www22.pair.com/csdc/ed3/ed3fre8.htm gives a reference that suggests it's the senior Cartan.

Comment: It is almost certainly Élie Cartan.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Élie for sure. The formula is derived in *Les systèmes differentiels extérieurs et leur applications géométriques* which was probably written before Henri was born. BTW, here is a very short proof that Chern showed me long ago.

- The exterior derivative is an anti-derivation of the exterior algebra
  and so is the interior product with a vector field while the Lie
  derivative is a derivation. (These are all trivial to check.)
- Also, the anti-commutator of two anti-derivations is a derivation. Hence
  both sides of the "magic formula" are derivations.
- It is obvious that
  two derivations are equal if they agree on 0-forms $f$ and exact
  1-forms $df$, since (locally) they generate the exterior algebra.
- Finally it is trivial that both sides of the magic formula agree on
  such forms.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that the formula is trivial for $1$-forms. To me that's the first (and only?) nontrivial case, and Chern's argument is a nice way to explain how to extend it to higher degree forms. But I'm just quibbling.

Comment: Phantastic! Answered in nanoseconds, plus question already listed by google.

Dick, I love Chern's proof. Many, if not most books suck on such matters. Similarly on could prove formula for differential in terms of covariant derivative. Can't tell of any book that doesn't introduce coordinates or bases/indices when treating such things.

Deane, the formula is quite trivial on differentials of functions (Lie derivative product rule) and is then extended to general 1-forms by product rule, since these are sums of fdg.

Comment: Sorry, Deane, you are correct---I screwed up. I should have said that it is obvious for functions $f$ and the differentials of functions, $df$, and that THESE generate the exterior algebra. The reason it is clear for $\omega = df$ is that the RHS becomes $di_X (df) = d(Xf)$.
On the other hand, since $d$ is "natural", i.e., commutes with diffeos, it also commutes with Lie derivatives, so the LHS becomes $d L_X f) $ which is also $d(Xf)$. 

Comment: /Les systèmes différentiels extérieurs et leurs applications géométriques/ seems to have been written in 1945. Henri was certainly born at this date.

Comment: @Martin Gisser. I love Chern's proof too, but my original reaction was total embarrassment! I proudly showed Chern an ugly several page long computational proof, and he said "Yes, Dick, BUT..." and then showed me the above argument in a couple of lines on a blackboard. :-(

Comment: ... Henri lived 1904-2008. One of my favorite centennials, after Vietoris (1891-2002).

Comment: @Maxime. You are right. Henri was born in 1904, so he was already in his thirties when Elie gave the lectures on which the book was based in 1936-37.

Comment: @Dick. Umm, are you THE Palais - or his son? :-) 

Comment: I am THE Palais father. :-)   BTW, do you know about our co-authored book? See:  http://ode-math.com.

Comment: Oh, the book looks extremely yummy. Just had a short look. I'd love to learn more numerics (which I hated at university), esp. the Runge-Kutta/renormalization/Butcher/Hopf algebra connection...


Comment: Martin: Regarding coordinate-based proofs, there's a nice middle ground where you use semi-canonical coordinates: rectify the flow of the vector field so that it looks like $V = \partial/\partial{x_1}$. Then there isn't any crunchy and unenlightening coordinate juggling.

Comment: Dick, thanks for the clarification. Now I agree with you.

Comment: This formula already appears in É. Cartan's 1922 classic, Leçons sur les invariant intégraux.  I believe it's in Chapter IX, where he discusses the effect of `infinitesimal transformations' (i.e., vector fields) on differential forms.  Of course, Henri was alive then, but he was only 18.

Comment: Late to the party; but this proof can nowadays also be found in Loring Tu's "An Introduction to Manifolds", Theorem 20.10. (@MartinGisser)

Answer (score 20):

Certainly Henri Cartan was too young to contribute to this formula and his father Elie played a decisive role, but it is not clear to decide who invented it. Indeed the formula can also be found in the Théophile De Donder's book "Théorie des invariants intégraux" published in 1927. Exterior differential forms are called there "formes intégrales", the exterior differential operator is called "différentielle intégrale" and is denoted by D. Formula DD=0 and Stokes' formula are setted. The main reference for that is H. Poincaré (with contributions by Volterra, Cartan, Goursat, De Donder). The exterior product is called "produit intégral" and is denoted by [AB] (as in E. Cartan's text). The interior product is called "substitution intégrale" and is denoted by E. De Donder indicates there that this notion was introduced by H. Poincaré.
Then the magic formula is attributed to Edouard Goursat ( E. Goursat, Sur quelques points de la théorie des invariants intégraux, J. Math. Pures Appl. (7), t. I (1915), 241—259; Sur certains systèmes d'équations aux différentielles totales et sur une généralisation du problème de Pfaff, Ann. Fac. Sci. Toulouse, t. VII (1915)) and De Donder (Th. De Donder, Sur les invariants intégraux relatifs et leurs applications à la physique mathématique, Bull. Acad. Roy. Belgique, Classe des Sciences, fév. 1911, 50--70.).

Comment: Thanks for the history and references and welcome to MathOverflow!

Comment: I'll repeat my earlier comment to Dick's answer: "This formula already appears in É. Cartan's 1922 classic, Leçons sur les invariant intégraux. I believe it's in Chapter IX, where he discusses the effect of `infinitesimal transformations' (i.e., vector fields) on differential forms. Of course, Henri was alive then, but he was only 18."  This is probably why it is called "Cartan's formula".  I note that, in that work, Cartan attributes the definition of the exterior derivative itself to Goursat, but he doesn't attribute the above formula to anyone.

Comment: Dear @Robert: I suggest that you post an answer.

Comment: @Pierre:  It looks as though Frédéric has found references that go back before Cartan's first mention of the formula in print (which appears to be 1922).  I haven't gone to look at the Goursat and De Donder references that he cites, but, it appears that calling it 'Cartan's formula' (which, of course, Cartan never did) is historically inaccurate.  My comment was mainly to speculate that the 1922 reference may be *why* we call it the Cartan formula today.  It's odd that Cartan didn't credit Goursat (or De Donder?) in his 1922 book, since he certainly held him in great esteem.

Comment: Alas I'm too bad at French and decyphering French math books. I'm far away from the library, but last time I was unable to identify the magic formula in E. Cartan's book.

BTW the history of diff. forms seems quite messy. E.g. Poincare's lemma is due to Volterra. And Goursat called closed forms "exacte". There is an article by Hans Samelson: "Differential Forms, the Early Days; or the Story of Deahna's Theorem and of Volterra's Theorem" Am. Math. Monthly 108 (6): 552–530 http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/faculty/beeson/courses/Ma213/HistoryOfForms.pdf No mention of the magic formula there.

Comment: @Frédéric: Can you point out the formula in E. Goursat, Sur quelques points de la théorie des invariants intégraux, J. Math. Pures Appl. (7), t. I (1915) ? A PDF copy is here: portail.mathdoc.fr/JMPA/PDF/… Andrzej Trautman (2008) writes: "Around 1920, Elie Cartan defined a natural differential operator L(X) acting on fields of exterior forms. He noted that it commutes with the exterior derivative d and gave, in equation (5) on p. 84 in [2]" the magic formula. Reference [2] is Lecons sur les invariants integraux. See fuw.edu.pl/~amt/4Krupka.pdf – Martin Gisser 1 hour ago 


Comment: @Martin: One reason that Trautman says `around 1920' is that, according to its preface, Cartan's 1922 book is the write-up of a course he gave in the 'summer semester' of 1920-1. Thus, presumably, he knew the formula by then. Note also that the equation (5) you are referring to in Cartan's book is, literally for a 3-form only, but it's clear that Cartan meant this to be an illustrative example of the formula for all degrees $p$. He didn't give the general derivation because his notation would have made it cumbersome, but he clearly knew that, in principle, the proof was the same for all $p$.

Answer (score 8):

Actually it seems that this formula was proved by Théophile De Donder in 1911, as you can see in his paper in Bulletins de la Classe des Sciences de l'Académie Royale de Belgique : https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/273691#page/11/mode/1up , pages 50 to 70.
The interior product is denoted by E there.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to Henri Cartan
according to
3), Page 193 of: S.S. Chern, et al, Lectures on Differential Geometry, World Sci, Singapore, 2000.

Comment: I think the earlier answers have already conclusively ruled this out.

Comment: Dear Deane, to be precise, I think that the final version is due to Henri. It is originally due to Elie while the name "Lie derivative" is suggested by K. Yano.

Comment: Could you say more about how the final version is different from the earlier versions? And where did Yano first use the term "Lie derivative"?

Comment: According to an article by Andrzej Trautman (2008), the general Lie derivative on tensors got introduced by Władysław Ślebodziński (1931) and named "Lie derivative" (in German) by David van Dantzig (1932).

Trautman article: http://www.fuw.edu.pl/~amt/4Krupka.pdf